# MAC OS 10.11.6,macbook pro which has Integrated Graphics and Graphics card：GeForce GT 750M，but when I want to use GPU,but problems

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5BFe.png)

> Problem:F tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc:128] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == ( session->Run({{"x", x}}, {"y:0", "y_normalized:0"}, {}, &outputs)) (OK vs. Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device to node 'Cast': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/gpu:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>      [[Node: Cast = CastDstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_INT32, _device="/gpu:0"]])

Answer (score 0):

The GPU version is Linux only, see [requirements section](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html). You can install only CPU version on MAC OS.